# How can i prevent this negative white space in my website from appearing?

Tags: css, removing-whitespace

I have been working on fixing this problem for a while, my website at some pages that has less or few content, or if it's shown in a big screen, it shows white space right under the footer.

"as shown here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/harES.jpg)"

i tried using height:100% but it doesn't work if the screen is small, because if i put the height:100% in body{} it will cause elements inside the body to overlap over the body and cause white space.

"as shown here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS4fW.jpg)"

i have no idea what else to tinker with to prevent this white space.

- i tried to add height:100% in body,html (doesn't work on small screens when i add more element in my divs.

```
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 100%; */
    /* overflow: scroll; */
}
```

i expected the result to make the body always at 100% on all possible screens, but the element would overflow over the body and cause white spaces.

Comment: you are not providing enough info. We need to see your page code. Also, just from experience, your page container should be some kind of div under body, does your container have a 100% width and height?

Comment: what code do you need to see? should i copy the whole CSS? or HTML? code of the page? and yes all my containers are percentage, 100% in height and some are like 20% in width.

Comment: We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like content in the container is smaller than screen size? Then you may use `min-height:100vh` in main container style. This will make its minimum size equals to windows size. Example at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/olga-kashtanowa/pen/rgrgZg)

Comment: should i add the min-height to the (body,html) ? or do you mean to the container holding the pictures for example?

Comment: Hard to say for sure without seeing the code, but I think you should add it to black container (one with background picture).

Comment: I updated Codepen example, maybe it's more clear now, at least if you have a big display. Try it with and without max-heigh and you will see the difference.

Comment: I experimented with min-height and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you link us to your site so we can see the issue?

Comment: i will try to upload it in GitHub